# When will i use "Model" instead of any variable such as (m) in mvc view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

My controller code; PatientController.cs

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
   {            
        Patient patient = db.Patients.Find(id);            
        return View(patient); 
   }
```

My View code; Edit.cshtml

```
@model PatientChart.Models.Patient
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m=> m.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(m=> m.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=> m.Name)
        </div>
    </div>
```

output: name1

Why we do not use (Model => Model.Name) instead of (m=>m.Name)?
When Will i have to use "Model" instead of "m" or any other variable?

Comment: The lambda is an expression and the helper methods like Html.LabelFor will retrieve the property info from that expression to get the type, name, attributes, ... from that property

Comment: it doesn't matter, usually single letters are used as lambda parameters, lambda is a shorthand method that aims to reduce the code so `m` is preferred over `model`

Comment: @MohamedAhmed Most programmers are very lazy (so am I) and why use more than one letter when one is sufficient ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo My laziness level: I use just `x` for any parameter :))

Comment: You can use @Html.EditorForModel(Patient)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said in comments, single letters are the preferred for Lambda expressions. They're just helpers.

So if my model has a `Name` property in it, I can create a field for that specific property on my View by using a Lambda expression to target that exact property:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
```

This is easy to type but you can literally use anything in place of my `x` in the Lambda expression though.

`Model` on the other hand is actually a structured variable in your View.

You'll use it to loop through a list of objects:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.Name</td>
    </tr>
}
```

You can use it to count items in your model:

```
<p>
    Showing @Model.Count records.
</p>
```

And so on.

[This tutorial on MVC might help you to understand more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started) if you'd like to read it for reference.

Comment: I should use "Model " here because using Model i can access the value of the object's property.

Comment: I should use "Model " here because using Model i can access the value of the object's property. Why i do not use Model keyword here? Please Explain.